# Applying the squeeze theorem to a non-trigonometric function

Tags: limits

In a practice problem, I am supposed find the limit of the following using the squeeze theorem:

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1}$$

I understand how to apply the squeeze theorem with trigonometric expressions, but I am not sure what expression I am supposed to start with using an expression like this.

Here is my attempt:

$$
\text{for } 0\le x \le3\\0 \le \sqrt{3-x} \le \sqrt{3}\\ -1 \le \sqrt{3-x}-1 \le \sqrt{3} -1\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-1} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}-1} \le -1\\ \frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3}-1} \le\frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1} \le -\sqrt{6-x}+2
$$

Which then evaluates to the limit being `0`, which is the incorrect answer.

Comment: I think you should first rationalize the numerator or denominator before trying to apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Why do you want the squeeze lemma at all? Just rationalize both expressions and take the limit. I got $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: They just said to use the squeeze theorem to evaluate it.

Comment: @elimirks You have the right idea, but weren't careful enough in taking reciprocals. Here's a hint: suppose that $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. Then, taking reciprocals as you did above, $1 \leq 1/x \leq -1$. Hm!

Comment: I wouldn't use the squeeze theorem at all on this.